# What is the difference between "I fished around in the box for cashews" and "I poked around in the box for cashews"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

There is bowl of variety nuts such as cashews, peanuts, almonds, etc and they are mixed all together.

I just put my hand into the bowl and stir around until I can get a cashew.

It seems we can say "**I fished around in the bowl for cashews**" and "**I poked around in the bowl for cashews**".

What is the difference between "**I fished around in the bowl for cashews**" and "**I poked around in the bowl for cashews**"?

Comment: They're interchangeable. You can also say "searched" or "searched around." One might be more common in one region than another, though.

Answer (score 1):

"Poke" seems like a somewhat odd word choice for this action ("fish" is very natural). If there is any difference I would say that "poke" implies a fairly small collection, few enough that they don't settle together at the bottom of the container after being moved out of the way (does not work of course if the bowl does not have a flat bottom). But in any case it is only a minor implies rather than a strong it-therefore-follows.

Answer (score 1):

To "poke around" means to look here and there, without any strategy or pattern, not thoroughly. It's mostly used for larger places where a person would move around looking at things, like in a room, house or city. It could work in this context if you can't see any cashews, and you push things around a bit to try and expose some.

To "fish around" means to search through things to find what you're looking for. It fits this context well.